# How do I create a unit test that validates a XML file vs the XSD schema

Tags: xml, unit-testing, xsd

So i have this file call "taller1.xsd"

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="profesor" type="Profesor_Atributos"/>
    <xs:complexType name="Profesor_Atributos">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="id" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xs:element name="nombre" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xs:element name="apellido" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xs:element name="edad" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

And i also have this file call "taller1.xml"

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<profesor xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="taller1.xsd" >
  <id>a1</id>
  <nombre>Juan</nombre>
  <apellido>Pedro</apellido>
  <edad>30</edad>
</profesor>
```

I am working on visual studio code, and i need to create a unit test to validates the XML file vs the XSD schema

Comment: Use a XML parser (e.g. Xerces), enable the schema validation feature (https://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/faq-pcfp.html#faq-1) and parse the document from the unit test and detect exceptions as accordingly.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? There's a C# API for validating documents against a schema, what else do you need?